# Error when trying to turn a python script using ursina into an executable

Tags: python, cx-freeze, ursina

So I was using cx_Freeze in order to turn my python script using ursina into an executable but then this happened : [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU2AB.png)

What am I supposed to do?

This is what my folder content and setup.py file looked like when I had the error : [Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOQa8.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), please paste the error message as text into your question instead. Please also add relevant information to your question (e.g. Python version, cx_Freeze version, imports of your application, cx_Freeze setup script, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `'ursina'` to the `packages` list of the `build_exe_options` in the `setup.py` script.

EDIT: try also to add `src` to the `include_files` list of the `build_exe_options`:

```py
build_exe_options = {'packages': ['ursina'], 'include_files': ['src']}

# ...

setup(  name = ...,  # complete!
        ...
        options = {'build_exe': build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable(...)])
```

See the cx_Freeze [documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#distutils-setup-script) for further details.

Comment: I did that but it doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: @Onuelito Does the error message change once you have added `ursina` to the `packages` list of the `build_exe_options`?

Answer (score 0):

From the original Ursina engine's folder copy the `application.py` file and in the build folder, you will find `exe.win-amd64-3.9` folder , inside that there will be a folder named `lib`, inside that  there will be `ursina` folder you have to paste it here (if you are using default download location then this is the application.py's path: `C:\Users\welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\ursina\application.py`)